# Beautify the o/p of grep command

Tags: linux, shell-script, command-line, grep

I am writing a bash script. It runs a couple of grep commands, and record the output of the grep command, in a text file. I am getting the output, but it is not formatted, so it is very difficult to read. Any suggestion that I can use to format/beautify the output, would be appreciated. Currently the script is:

```
 validateError=$(grep {some command} / -1)
 echo ${validateError}\n | sudo tee -a ./validation_logs/${hostname}_result.log

 echo "----------------------------\n" | sudo tee -a ./validation_logs/${hostname}_result.log

 echo "grep -B 3 'ps -eaf|grep -i snitch' ${hostname}_result.log\n" > ./validation_logs/${hostname}_result.log
 validateProcess=$(grep {somecommand} / -1)
 echo ${validateProcess}\n | sudo tee -a ./validation_logs/${hostname}_result.log
```

Comment: We don't know what your output looks like or how you want it to look.  Can you please provide both of these critical pieces of information?

Comment: **ESC]0;**<Hostname>**:^GESC[41;37**mroot@**ESC****[46;30m**<Hostname>**ESC[0m** Tue Sep 17 00:25:35 /datadrive/home/darwhs **^M**

Comment: in bold you can see thespecial characters are getting added, I am not sure from where it is getting added